# laravel 5.5: post a form with multiple number of dynamically created fields with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5.5

in my laravel 5.5 project, every job post has many questions and every question has many answers and every answer can be acceptable or unacceptable. i am coding a view that is responsible for adding questions. this is my initial form:

```
 <form action="{{route('questions.store')}}" class="form" id="form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {{csrf_field()}}
            <div class="q">
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="box-header">
                        <strong>سوال</strong> <strong id="number">1</strong>
                    </div>
                    <div class="question">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">؟</span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="متن سوال" name="question">
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><input value="1" type="checkbox"></span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" required placeholder="  پاسخ اول" >
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><input value="0" type="checkbox"></span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="  پاسخ دوم">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><input value="0" type="checkbox"></span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="  پاسخ سوم">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><input value="0" type="checkbox"></span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="  پاسخ چهارم">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                <div>
                    <button type="button" id="add" class="btn btn-warning">more questions</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn submit btn-primary">submit</button>
                </div>

        </form>
```

i added a script so every time user clicks on more questions, another question adds to the form:

```
<script>
        var number = 1;
    $('#add').click(function () {
        number = number + 1;
        $('.q').append($('<div class="box">\n' +
            '                        <div class="box-header">\n' +
            '                            <strong>سوال</strong>  <strong id="number">'+ number + '</strong>\n' +
            '                        </div>\n' +
            '                    <div class="">\n' +
            '                        <div class="input-group">\n' +
            '                            <span class="input-group-addon">؟</span>\n' +
            '                            <input type="text" class="question form-control" placeholder="متن سوال">\n' +
            '                        </div>\n' +
            '                        <div class="input-group">\n' +
            '                            <span class="input-group-addon"><input value="1" type="checkbox"></span>\n' +
            '                            <input type="text" class="answer form-control" required placeholder="  پاسخ اول">\n' +
            '                            <span class="input-group-addon"><input value="0" type="checkbox"></span>\n' +
            '                            <input type="text" class="answer form-control" placeholder="  پاسخ دوم">\n' +
            '                            <span class="input-group-addon"><input value="0" type="checkbox"></span>\n' +
            '                            <input type="text" class="answer form-control" placeholder="  پاسخ سوم">\n' +
            '                            <span class="input-group-addon"><input value="0" type="checkbox"></span>\n' +
            '                            <input type="text" class="answer form-control" placeholder="  پاسخ چهارم">\n' +
            '                        </div>\n' +
            '                    </div>\n' +
            '                </div>'));
    })
</script>
```

every checkbox should determine whether or not the answer is acceptable. now i want to submit this form using ajax. however i dont know how to collect all questions and their answers in request so i can access them in controller.

Comment: you want to get the multiple dynamically created fields?

Comment: @tech_geek yes. i want to know how i get all of their values and answers

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38207373/how-to-get-value-of-dynamically-generated-textbox-with-same-id-using-ajax-php)

Answer (score 0):

if i understood. You need send values of elements as add dynamically?

If that true, You can use following code;

```
$("#form").submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        data: $("form").serialize(),
        ...rest
    });
});
```

In the above code this line `data: $("form").serialize()` provides all form elements send to your controller with ajax.

i think, that will be solve your problem.

Comment: i dont know how to name my dynamic inputs to be able to retrieve them in controller

Comment: You should generating as dynamic their names. When you generating input you must set each input name.

Let's you want "name" input for visitor name. You should set name with "**_**" prefix and increment number value.

For example. 
**name_1
name_2**

So, you can catch them in your controller's on post action with php foreach.